# Login denied after installation of Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, users

I've tried to install Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit on a Dell XPS M1530.  After installation I seem to have no user created.  I am only able to log in as guest.  When I switch to the console it will not accept my user name and password.  When I do a safe restart it recognises my user name and gives me a console with `username@blar>` prompt. Is there something I need to do to create a user with such privileges or actually any user at all.

Comment: Welcome to AU! Can you provide the content of `/var/log/auth.log`? Refer to “[How do I get information from the logs on my computer when I only have access to the command line?](/q/440087/175814)” if you need help extracting it and [edit] your question to link to it (so all the necessary info is in one place and not cluttered throughout the comments).

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have accidentally installed in OEM mode.
Add user manually, according to [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AddUsersHowto) for example. You should better use a new username.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I think i provided enough information to find another manual if this one is down. "Add new user from command line". Otherwise, I will have to either copy-paste 1.5 pages of text or risk forgetting some critical detail.